# Can we use Address of operator "&" inline GCC ARM assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

Can we use Address of operator "&" inline GCC ARM assembly? If yes then I have a structure core_regx and I need to pass the address of a member r0 of that strucutre into the below mentioned code:

```
asm volatile("ldr r3, [%0,#0]":: "r" (&(core_reg->r0)));
```

Please check if this code is correct or not.

Comment: I believe that any expression is valid for an input argument, as long as its type is appropriate.

Comment: Actaully, this is only a part of the whole inline assembly code so if any error comes I wont be able to check it cause I am not having a microcontroller to test it I am having a TI -OMAP based chipset to check it.

Comment: You don't need a microcontroller to test it. Just compile it and see if it behaves as you expect. You might also want to have a look at this: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html

Comment: Yes Bill, I am porting Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can use **&**.  However, I would suggest that your assembler specifiers may have some issues and better options.

```
asm volatile("ldr r3, %0":: "m" (core_reg->r0) : "r3");
```

You definitely should add **r3** to the clobber list.  Also, the `"m"` specifier is probably better.  If `core_reg` is already in `r0`, the compiler can use the offset of `r0` member and generate code such as,

```
       add r0, r0, #12    ; assuming r0 is core_reg.
       ldr r3, [r0]
```

The compiler knows the relation between `core_reg` and `core_reg->r0`.  At least `"m"` works well with some versions of `arm-xxx-gcc`.  Run `objdump --disassemble` on the code the compiler generates to verify it is doing what you want.

**Edit:** The GCC manual has lots of information, such as [Gcc assembler contraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html), [Machine specific](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) and [General Info](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  There are many tutorials on the Internet such as the [ARM assembler cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html), which is one of the best.

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful answer. Could you please provide me a good link to study it in more detail.